# Where to persist some data in windows application

Tags: .net, winforms

We are having a windows aplication(WPF .net 3.5) that client will be installing using ClickOne full trust.

At first startup user enters credential which are being used to communicate with server.

I need to persist those credential some where in windows app so it would be used by application to function.

Where and how could i save it?

I am new to window application world so please ignore my dummyness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Windows `Registry` as encrypted values, or in `Application Data` as encrypted files.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, although I really hate applications that make use of the Registry and/or the Application Data folder as it makes them so much less portable!

Comment: What(Function) can give me that path for application data folder? I assume by default application has full access to that folder, right?

Comment: you can use the `%APPDATA%` OS constant in your filepath string

Comment: Thanks, Looks like i can use IsolatedStorageFile which is intended for this purpose and gives lot of flexibility.